# How to select MAX for each type in one request

Tags: php, sql

I use mysql 5.1.

This is my DB schema :

```
id     user_id     type     created_at
1       32          X       2012-11-19
2       32          Y       2012-11-18
3       30          X       2012-11-16
4       32          Z       2012-11-17
5       31          Y       2012-11-13
6       32          Z       2012-11-9
```

I want that my SQL query returns the `user_id`, `type`, and the lastest  `created_at` for each type.
I tried to make this request: 
`SELECT max(type) FROM notification WHERE user_id=34 ORDER BY type` but it returns only the latest `created_at`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in really simple query because `GROUP BY` (which you are missing by the way in your query) doesn't guarantee that it won't return values mixed from multiple rows.

```sql
SELECT * FROM notifications AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT type, MAX(`created_at`) AS max_created_at
    FROM notification
    WHERE user_id=34
    GROUP BY `type`
) AS t2
    ON t1.type = t2.type
        AND t1.created_at = t2.max_created_at
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select n.id, n.user_id, n.type, m.max_created_at
from notification n
     inner join
     (
         select   type, max(created_at) as max_created_at
         from     notification
         group by type
     ) m  on n.type = m.type and 
             m.max_created_at = n.created_at
```

Note this does assume that there are not two records with the same type and created_at date.

Comment: It returns, #1052 - Column 'type' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Now, #1054 - Unknown column 'm.type' in 'on clause'

Comment: `+1` @Tom-pouce this will work, the user only forgot to add `type` on the subquery. try it again.

Comment: @KuyaJohn Yes it works but it returns the lastest result by type, not for a particular user. Vyktor answer is perfect. +1 for you Steve Homer, thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Tom-pouce you only need to have append `WHERE n.user_id=34` and it will surely word :D

Answer (score 0):

The following query selects the highest `created_at` for each type:

```
SELECT type, MAX(created_at) FROM notification GROUP BY type ORDER BY type
```

Not sure how you want to combine that with user, your question isn't precise enough.

The following query selects the highest `created_at` for each type for a specific user:

```
SELECT user, type, MAX(created_at) 
  FROM notification 
 WHERE user = 34
 GROUP BY type, user 
 ORDER BY type, user
```

Comment: I want the lastest of each type for a specific user_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, type, max(created_at) FROM notification WHERE user_id=34 GROUP BY user_id,type ORDER BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(type) FROM notification WHERE user_id=34 ORDER BY type
```

try to revise like this

```
SELECT user_id, type,created_at FROM notification WHERE user_id=34 ORDER BY type
```

then if you want to see from latest to oldest or oldest to lastest

add `ASC` or `DESC` order